# QTest is not showing dialogs

Tags: c++, qt, qttest

**Qt 4.7.1**

I have a qttest setup which has until recently been performing well. I have encountered, and dealt with, the need to interact with modal dialogs by using singleshot timers.

However, I am now seeing the opposite behaviour; calls such as QFileDialog::getSaveFileName are returning straight away with no display of the dialog. This is since I performed a merge so I assume there is some code or build change behind it, but it isn't the function call itself.

As far as example code goes, I can't post my whole framework or AUT but the consider the following inside a test function:

```
QMessageBox::StandardButton button = QMessageBox::question(NULL,"Thing",
        "Do you want to do a thing?",
        QMessageBox::StandardButton::Yes | QMessageBox::StandardButton::No);
```

The call returns straight away and button is set to NoButton. I should add that there is a bit of a framework around my tests and I manually start each test with QTest::qExec. (The framework has not changed, of that I'm sure)

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Edit:

The eventloop started by the messagebox in the above example has quitNow set to true, which is causing exec to return straight away. I'm now looking for why this is set, in the meantime feel free to enlighten me!

Answer (score 0):

This was due to calling qApp->exit() in my cleanup() function. There is no need to do this!